# issues with webscraping loop in rvest

Tags: r

I have a couple of issues that I cannot find a reasonable solution for through searching. I am working on scraping citation information from journals and am having a little hitch when it comes to compiling them in a dataframe.

This code scrapes well, but the big issue is that it creates one long vector instead of a table. Thats the first issue.

The second issue is that if I try to load in the webpages from a csv file, the script will not run. I will get the following error:

> Error in UseMethod("read_xml") :    no applicable method for
>   'read_xml' applied to an object of class "factor"

That is just a csv with the urls listed.

The third and final issue is that an article might have more than one email and thus more than one row. The code ignores this. For example, the paper
http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.3102/0013189X17737739

```
library(rvest)
data<- c("http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.3102/0013189X037001060", 
  "http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.3102/0013189X037002102",
  "http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.3102/0013189X037002104",
  "http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.3102/0013189X17737739")

scrape <- function(x){
  doc<-read_html(x)
  author <- html_text(html_nodes(doc, '.art_authors'))
  year <- html_text(html_nodes(doc, '.year'))
  journalName <- html_text(html_nodes(doc, '.journalName'))
  art_title <- html_text(html_nodes(doc, '.art_title'))
  volume <- html_text(html_nodes(doc, '.volume'))
  page <- html_text(html_nodes(doc, '.page'))
  email <- html_text(html_nodes(doc, xpath = "//a[@class = 'email']"))

  Author = ifelse(length(author)==0, NA, author)
  Year = ifelse(length(year)==0, NA, year)
  Journal_Name = ifelse(length(journalName)==0, NA, journalName) 
  Art_Title = ifelse(length(art_title)==0, NA, art_title)
  Volume = ifelse(length(volume)==0, NA, volume)
  Page = ifelse(length(page)==0, NA, page)
  Email = ifelse(length(email)==0, NA, email)

  row<-cbind(Author, Year, Journal_Name, Art_Title, Volume, Page, Email)
}

y <- lapply (data, scrape)

View (y)
```

when I try to do run the script from a csv

```
data<- read.csv ("link_test.csv")
y <- lapply (data$link, scrape)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably after the `read.csv` characters are imported as factors. You can change that with the argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` or you convert the column after the import with `as.character(data$link)`

Comment: thanks, that was a quick fix for the csv. it had completely escaped my mind that I needed to convert to characters. Just need to iron out the issue with compiling the table now.

Answer (score 2):

If you call this function as last line, you'll get what you want ;)

```
y <- do.call(rbind, y)

library(DT)
datatable(y)
```

For several email adresses you should change the last but one line of the function to:

```
  Email = ifelse(length(email)==0, NA, 
          ifelse(length(email)==1, email, paste(email, collapse=" ; ")))
```

But I didn't test that, as I didnt find any webpages with several E-mail adresses.

Comment: This works well but the issue comes when an article has more than one email and thus constitute more than one row.

Comment: They are combining the emails into a single cell separated by a " ; ". That's the point of paste(...,collapse = " ; "). You have choices here: 1) repeat all the data in a row except for the email which will be different, 2) combine the email into a single cell separated by a character, 3) create a column for each potential email and leave extra columns filled with NA. Since you haven't told us why you need it in one of these ways people are assuming you can just put all the emails in the same cell.

Answer (score 1):

For the csv, it's hard to answer without seeing the file structure, at least a couple rows.  However, the problem might be solved by this:

```
# bind your list items together as rows
df <- do.call(rbind, y)
# ensure each column is class character rather than factors
df <- as.data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

EDIT: updating to answer your edit.
In some webpages there are multiple authors, which the webpage seems to present all in one node, as a comma-separated text string.  The code you posted does not seem to return any emails for your example webpages.  However, if it did return a list or vector of emails, you could collapse them by pasting as shown below:

```
Email = ifelse(length(email)==0, NA, do.call(paste, email, sep = ", "))
```

Comment: This works well but the issue comes when an article has more than one email and thus constitute more than one row.